# How to find the best path in graph with weighted nodes and vertices

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Let's say I have this graph

[image: example graph]

- always a full graph
- one start node - also the finish node
- weighted nodes and vertices

I want to find a path short as possible but with the best score (sum of points of nodes) - in other words a path that can't be longer then some defined constant but give me the best amount of points. And I want to start and stop in the same node and don't want to go over already visited nodes.

Are there any algorithms which could help me with this problem or do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Oh, and it's *not* a homework, I just want to create a special path finder.

**EDIT**

So far I've been able to construct a working algorithm which can find some path in a few seconds. But I don't get the amount of points I'd like to - I get only about 85% of the desired score. And if I change the algoritm's parameters then time will be in hours and more...

Comment: Is the graph directed? Otherwise: find the minimal weight edge `(u,v)` such that `u` is your source and `(u,v),(v,u)` is the shortest path. You didn't mention any problems using the same edge twice.

Comment: It's not directed. Of course I can't use the same edge twice - that will break the condition that I can't go over already visited nodes.

Comment: You must visit the source twice if it is also the destination node, as you said. the path will be: `v -> ... -> v`, and `v` must be visited twice.

Comment: So @Tomas, is the solution `(start,v) -> (v,start)` feasible in your situation?

Comment: I forgot that - only source can be visited twice. But your simple path is not good - not enough points. `start -> 5p -> 2p -> start` would give me more points and the same length. One of possible solutions could be also this: `start -> 5p -> 8p -> start` (depending on the maximum allowed length).

Comment: Oh, you want the **most points**? not least points?

Comment: Yes :) I said it in the question...

Comment: This sounds a lot like a variant of traveling salesman. For that, there are tons of pretty good heuristic algorithms around. A quick google search will point you to research papers as well as implementations.

Comment: But TS goes over all nodes, I don't want that. But maybe I could use similar heuristic for my current algorithm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is solvable in better than brute force time.  You could calculate *all* paths up to a certain constraint length.  However, for an arbitrarily large graph that would be extremely slow.  If you're looking for a solid guess, I'd start with a greedy algorithm that picks the step with the highest Points per Length value, until the limit is reached.  You can then add things such as reversing in the case of premature filling (say, if you've gone 5, but your limit is 6, and your current node has no paths of length one connected) to find out how that works.

Comment: I think you're right. It seems to be an NP problem. I don't know how to combine an effective algorithm with path finding. Brute force with heuristics and branch and bound is still useless - the time is enormous because I have about 80 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would actually work, but these are my initial thoughts:

Perhaps try with the maximum spanning tree (Prim's or Kruskal's). Since you don't want to repeat vertices, your path must end up being the [cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) graph. Walk the spanning tree (maybe some sort of greedy algorithm?) and once you hit a leaf, go back to the start vertex (since the original graph was the complete graph). This would only work (maybe) if there were no negative edge weights.

Just some thoughts for now - it's late at night, I'll take a closer look in the morning. :)